# Why Azure DevOps PAT is expiring so quickly?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I built a project that uses PAT (Personal Access Token) generated by a user to connect to Azure DevOps REST API and get some data about a project and its commits, etc..
It happened to me twice now that the request returns with:

> Access Denied: The Personal Access Token used has expired

Even though the token is not expired yet, it's been created two days ago.

Is there any limitation on using this RestAPI which if I exceeded it'll expire my token automatically?

Comment: I created a new PAT and used it only in one server, this issue did not show again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check with the user if the PAT has expired, because `Expiration` can be customized.

[image]

If the PAT confirms that it has not expired, you can try to re-create a new PAT, select `All accessible organizations` and `Full access` scope , revoke the previous PAT, and see if the new PAT is available.

[image]

In this [case](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/4285bd6f-785d-4775-977b-0a7c7acea057?category=windowsazurewebsitespreview) with the similar issue, a contributor provided a solution : the user was able to fix it by signing out and back in. This seemed to refresh the auth token and unblocked them. You can also try it .